# how to use 'checkForBadJavascirpts'

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I want to use grease monkey for an client-side javascript debug. The user.js I want to use is 'checkForBadJavascript'. See this link: https://gist.github.com/BrockA/2620593

For example, I want to replace the "http://jsbin.com/evilExternalJS/js" in the following html page with another js called "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js", what should I do in the user.js of grease monkey?

```
<body onload="init()">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jsbin.com/evilExternalJS/js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function init () {
    var newParagraph            = document.createElement ('p');
    newParagraph.textContent    = "I was added by the old, evil init() function!";
    document.body.appendChild (newParagraph);
}
</script>
```

I tried something like this:

```
checkForBadJavascripts ( [
[false, /old, evil init()/, function () {addJS_Node (init);} ],
[true, /evilExternalJS/i, function(){addJS_Node(null,"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js",null);} ]
```

] );

But in the Firebug, it has something like this:

```
<script src="http://jsbin.com/evilExternalJS/js" type="text/javascript">
Reload the page to get source for: http://jsbin.com/evilExternalJS/js
</script>
```

Any comments? By the way, why the regular expression of "http://jsbin.com/evilExternalJS/js" is '/evilExternalJS/i'? (this can be seen in the source code of 'checkForBadScripts'). What does the 'i' for?

Comment: are you saying it's not working? if so, post your test page. it's important to see the order of all the `<script>` tags you mention. the Firebug message probably just has to do with some optimization that keeps it from snooping on script loads when Firebug isn't running.

Comment: The test page I use is http://jsbin.com/ogudon/1 .

Comment: There is too many questions. Why would you want to disable jquery? And replace for what? Do you know what jquery is? If you just wanna block a script on the page, you could use AdBlock Plus firefox addon. evilExternalJS is the name of the script file on src, then you have to select the name with regular expressions, something unique to that script
checkForBadJavascripts ( [[true, /nameofthescript/, ... ]] );
i on regular expressions means ignore case-sensitive. And I assume you are using // @require https://gist.github.com/raw/2620135/checkForBadJavascripts.js on the head of your userscript.

Comment: I suggest you copy this: 
checkForBadJavascripts [greasemonkey]
and paste on the stackoverflow's search, 
then read all questions and answers

Comment: This is really helpful. By the way, jquery is just an example for this question. The core for this question is that I want to make a client-side debug tools, which means every time you find something wrong in the compressed javascript codes, you can replace it with the original codes from your server and easy to debug.